# Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at xyz.com (“default-src”) issue

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I'm getting the following issue:

```
Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob:https://test.com/ff851-924-4522-8b74-f1d4f8c9f (“default-src”).
```

whenever I click `Export` button which exports user data in Mozilla Firefox browser. The file is also not getting downloaded.
The same is working fine in Google Chrome perfectly.

I tried including the following meta tag in html file but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' blob:">
```

Any way to get around this issue?

Comment: _Is_ your user data export an image? If not, then a CSP setting for `img-src` is likely not going to help.

Comment: It says `(“default-src”)` at the end of the error message, so _that's_ likely what you need to allow `blob` URLs for - unless you can find anything more specific than that (we don't know what exactly your button actually does.)

Comment: @CBroe The specified issue is happening on blob type (its a csv file). I added img too as in another place same issue was happening for images. Tried adding `default-src` too but that doesn't seem to help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a content security policy set on your page, you can likely see it in the response headers. You need to identify where the policy is set and modify it to allow "blob:" in default-src or a more specific directive. Adding another policy in meta can only make the total policy stricter.

Comment: Thanks for your insights Halvor. This was indeed the solution I was looking for. I have added a more detailed solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @HalvorSakshaug 's answer, this issue was indeed caused due to the CSP configuration set in source, in my case Cloudfront. I modified it to allow blob and its working now.

To create/update CSP in cloudfront,

1. Cloudfront > Functions > Create function
2. The handler can be defined as:

   ```
   function handler(event) {
    var response = event.response;
    var headers = response.headers;
    headers['content-security-policy'] = {
        value: "default-src 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ https://fonts.gstatic.com/; script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-hashes' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ https://fonts.gstatic.com/ "
    };
    return response;}
   ```

This can be used in configuration in behavior as:

1. Distributions > DistrubtionID > default > Edit Behavior
2. Function Associations > Viewer Response > Cloudfront Functions > function-name-created-earlier